# OData ASP.Net Core Get Related Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I've got an OData Beta + ASP.Net Core + EF project. I'm trying to work out the OData controller functions and I'm getting an error trying to return the related entities:

Models / Customer.cs

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Standing { get; set; }

    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

CustomersController.cs

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Bookings_Server.EF;
using Bookings_Server.OData.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Bookings_Server.OData.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ODataRoutePrefix("customers")]
    public class CustomersController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public CustomersController(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("({key})/people")]
public IQueryable<Customer> GetPeople([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    var result = _context.Customers.Where(m => m.Id == key).Select(m => m.People).ToList();
    return (result);
}
}
```

I'm getting an intellisense error under the result variable (within the return) stating:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<Bookings_Server.OData.Models.Person>>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Bookings_Server.OData.Models.Customer>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I've been looking at other OData V4 examples but they all throw implicit convert errors (assuming this is the difference of working on Aps.Net Core).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: you need to understand the difference between an `IQueryable<T>`, which represents a (normally) database query, with an `IEnumerable<T>`, which represents an in-memory collection or data source. So:

```
// WRONG
public IQueryable<Customer> GetPeople([FromODataUri] int key)

// CORRECT
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetPeople([FromODataUri] int key)
```

You should never return to outside your application an Entity Framework query.

Second, you want to *include* data from related entities, not *select* that data. So:

```
// WRONG
return _context.Customers
    .Where(m => m.Id == key)
    .Select(m => m.People) // "only give me People data"
    .ToList();

// CORRECT
return _context.Customers
    .Where(m => m.Id == key)
    .Include(m => m.People) // "give me Customer WITH People data"
    .ToList();
```

Mix these constructs and you end up with:

```
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("customers({key})/people")]
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetPeople([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    return _context.Customers
        .Where(m => m.Id == key)
        .Include(m => m.People)
        .ToList();
}
```

One more thing to note, is that you should always use the asynchronous versions of Entity Framework Core's data access methods:

```
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("customers({key})/people")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetPeople([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    return await _context.Customers
        .Where(m => m.Id == key)
        .Include(m => m.People)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

As a last comment, you should prefer returning the built-in `IActionResult` that allows you to easily change the response without having to throw exceptions:

```
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("customers({key})/people")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPeople([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    var customers = await _context.Customers
        .Where(m => m.Id == key)
        .Include(m => m.People)
        .ToListAsync();

    // this is only an example
    if (!customers.Any())
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(customers);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @camilo! as someone new to development I'm still in the monkey-see monkey-do phase so your articulate and careful answer is perfect in helping me learn and not just get a fix! Many thanks!!!

Your final code block didn't quite work for me. After adding the missing namespaces I'm still getting `the name Json does not exist in the current context` so I'll conitnue trying to work out how to resolve that today. Cheers, Adam

Comment: @leadfollowmove The way of saying thanks around here is by upvoting and accepting helpful answers :) For the last block, I assumed that the method is inside a class that inherits `Controller`, but that assumption is wrong I see. Can you add the class declaration?

Comment: I appreciate the update. I've edited the controller class details to show the rest of the controller (minus the working functions) which hopefully provides sufficient infomation to show what I'm missing. Cheers, Adam

Comment: @leadfollowmove Ah, it seems that you should be using `Ok` instead of `Json`, I've updated the answer

Comment: Just to make things complicated, I happened to try that this morning and it doesn't work. The intellisense is happy, but I then get an Internal Server error at runtime: `An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The path template 'customers({key})/people' on the action 'GetPeople' in controller 'Customers' is not a valid OData path template. Found an unresolved path segment 'people' in the OData path template 'customers({key})/people'.`

Comment: Camilo (@camilo)or anyone else have any thoughts on how to solve this last hurdle? Cheers, Adam

Answer (score 0):

Okay. With some help I managed to solve this issue. I didn't realise the [OdataRoute] is case sensitive and it was picking up People in my model and was having an issue with the fact it was people in my controller.

Changed this and everything started working as @camilo proposed.